# Appending a number to LPCTSTR

Tags: c, string, winapi

How do you append a number to an LPCTSTR?  A library I am using takes an LPCTSTR for a com port address.  I know how to do this with char* , but not with a LPCTSTR.  This is what I want to do (assuming sprintf as is worked with these, which I know it doesn't)

```
LPCTSTR PortString;
int ComPortNumber;

sprintf(PortString,"COM%d",ComPortNumber);
```

Such that when that is done, the LPCTSTR PortString, would contain "COM9" if 9 was stored in the ComPortNumber integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An LPCTSTR is a pointer to a TCHAR - in other words a pointer to a string. In the code snippet you provide, it points to some random area of memory and running the code is undefined behavior since you are accessing some random area of memory by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Try this code instead:

```
TCHAR PortString[64];
int ComPortNumber;

/* assign some value to ComPortNumber here */

_sntprintf_s(
    PortString,                       // The buffer for the output
    sizeof(PortString)/sizeof(TCHAR), // The number of TCHARs in the buffer
    _TRUNCATE,                        // How to handle overflows
    _T("COM%d"),                      // The format string
    ComPortNumber);                   // And the port number, finally!
```

I used the `T` variants of the calls and types to ensure that you code would compile in both ANSI/MBCS  and UNICODE modes, and the new "secure" variant of `_sntprintf` to help reduce the chance of buffer overrruns.

In real production code you should check the return address from the `_sntprintf_s` call for errors.

One last point: be careful to **not** return `PortString` to whoever calls this function, as it is stack based, and when this function exits, the buffer will disappear. If you do this your program will crash while you're debugging/testing if you're lucky. If you're not lucky, it may *appear* to work correctly but it will be a ticking timebomb.

Comment: WHen I tried this, I got Unhandled Exception:  Access violation writing location 0x00000000.  I am not returning this string, (since this part is in the Main, but I am handing it off to another function to do the Com Port setup.

Comment: @Xantham: I can assure you the above code is correct and the error you cite cannot be generated by the code, as written. Are you sure the crash occurs in this block of code? Can you show us the *actual* code that you tried? Did you copy-paste it? Did you make any changes?

Comment: agree - more context is needed if this is failing for you

Comment: You are right, the error was elsewhere in the code for that error.  As a more general question, how did you know this answer?  There are several different variations of sprintf, and how could I (without asking online here) figure this out myself?  There are so many with only small differences in the documentation, that I do not know how I would solve this without asking.

Comment: Well, the short answer is "experience". The only slighty longer answer is "searching MSDN a bit plus experience". This is the sort of thing you learn once when you stumble upon it and then you just use.

Comment: Because `TCHAR` is a *single* character. You were attempting to assign an array of `TCHAR`s to a single `TCHAR` - it wouldn't fit. In my code I allocate an array an array of `TCHAR`s and dynamically format the string inside them.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  WinAPI is a very confusing thing to try to learn by oneself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the secure versions from tchar.h.

```
TCHAR PortString[32];
int ComPortNumber;

_stprintf_s( PortString, 32, _T("COM%d"), ComPortNumber );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The API with the LPCTSTR is declaring that parameter as constant string to indicate to you that it will not modify the string it's given. You can still pass in a non-constant string to this API.

So you can do:

```
CHAR PortString[32];
int ComPortNumber;

sprintf(PortString,"COM%d",ComPortNumber);
```

Comment: I think `snprintf` is preferred to `sprintf` these days

Comment: Just make sure you don't return `PortString` from whatever function contains this chunk of code. Or else... *boom*

Comment: When I tried this, I get the error:  error C2664: 'SetupComPort' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CHAR [32]' to 'LPCTSTR', where SetupComPort is the function that takes in a LPCTSTR as an argument.

Comment: The "problem" is that you are compiling in UNICODE, and LPCTSTR is a pointer to a wchar_t, whereas CHAR is a char - the two types are fundamentally different. The `<tchar.h>` macros were designed to abstract this difference. Look at some of the answers which show how to use TCHAR instead.

Answer (score 0):

`LPCTSTR` is merely a `const TCHAR *`, which you use when you accept it as a parameter.

You would want to allocate the string as an array instead. Also, use the generic text mapping:

```
TCHAR PortString[20];
int ComPortNumber;

_stprintf(PortString,_T("COM%d"),ComPortNumber);
```

and include tchar.h.

Comment: The point of `TCHAR` stuff is to be agnosting about whether it's `CHAR` or `WCHAR` (`LPSTR` or `LPWSTR`, etc.). This answer doesn't apply with active `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` defines.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `TCHAR` stuff:

Use [`_stprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fill a `TCHAR` buffer, which should be an array:

```
TCHAR PortString[32]; /* as another answer says */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CString` and then when you're all done appending stuff to it, you can call the [`CString::operator LPCSTR() const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)   on it to get the `LPCSTR` from it.

Answer (score 0):

LPCTSTR is a typedef for either const char* or const wchar_t*. Do it just like you would with char* but with [_stprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Please use `_sntprintf_s` instead. The `_s` variants of the string functions help prevent bugs and improve the security of your program.